# Detecting when new document is opened in Gedit plugin

Tags: gtk, gedit, gedit-plugin

I'm working on a plugin for the text editor Gedit in which I need to know when a new document is opened. Is there a signal which is emitted when that happens? The method `do_activate` in the `ViewActivatable` extension point is called when a new view (tab) is created but when a document is opened in an empty Gedit session the tab "Unsaved Document 1" is reused so no new view is created.

Answer (score 1):

Gedit changes the window title to the title of the open document. This happens whenever you open or rename a document or switch between document tabs. I don't know exactly how a plugin is executed, but I believe it is possible to use `Gtk.Label.connect("notify::label", your_callback_function)` in **Gtk.Label** responsible for the title to detect this change and thus know if a new document has been open.

Of course, you will need to filter changes that occur due to switching tabs or renaming the file, but that doesn't seem like a big problem to me.